# pdf file couldn't save using ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, pdf, download, http-post

I have rest endpoint like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadPdf(@RequestBody ReportData reportData) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(reportData.getFileName(), reportData.getFileName() + ".pdf");

    try {
        byte[] generatedPdf = downloadService.getPdf(reportData.getUrl(), reportData.getParams(), reportData.getReportName());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(generatedPdf, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error downloading report.", e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

I'm calling it using ajax like this;

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            url: 'api/download/pdf',
            data: JSON.stringify(constructPostData()),
            success: function (result) {
                var blob = new Blob([result], {type: "application/pdf"});
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = reportName;
                link.click();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                console.log(status);
            }
        });
```

but this only gives me an empty pdf. 
if I hit this with rest client and download pdf from there I can see the correct pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I have change the ajax request like bellow and its working

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        xhrFields: {
                        responseType: 'blob'
                    },
        url: 'api/download/pdf',
        data: JSON.stringify(constructPostData()),
        success: function (result) {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(result);
            link.download = reportName;
            link.click();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
```